# Why does "pkg-config" print only a blank space with the "--cflags" option?

Tags: compiling, gcc, pkg-config

I installed libcurl using :`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`. When I try to compile my program I read that we have to pass where libcurl is located to the GCC compiler(although for me its located at /usr/include).
Therefore according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1175115 I compiled it using

```
gcc myfile.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl) -o myprogram
```

But if I only enter `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` it prints nothing (only a blank space). The program compiles correctly if I add the flag and `--libs`. I only do not understand why `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` returns nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `--cflags` is intended to give you any pre-processor or compile flags *required* for the packages/libraries on the command-line; you get a blank space because there are no such required flags for *libcurl*; that's perfectly normal.

Comment: Okay. It seems to make sense now

Comment: Another reason that `--cflags` would return nothing is because default paths are not returned, to avoid duplication: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362297/36693

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the command that prints nothing?

You have `pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl` in the `$()` in your `gcc` command, which you say works. But you've referred to the `pkg-config` command you're running to see the output as `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` *without `--libs`*.

Is it possible you're just running a different command inside the `$()` in the `gcc` command as you are separately to check the output?

To clarify, while the manpage is a bit confusing, the actual behavior of the two commands *is different*. This is from my Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 machine with `libcurl4-openssl-dev` installed:

```
ek@Apok:~$ pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl
 -lcurl  
ek@Apok:~$ pkg-config --cflags libcurl

ek@Apok:~$
```

Comment: pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl print the same thing as  pkg-config --libs libcurl. When I enter pkg-config --cflags it prints nothing.The typo has been fixed. Hope that helps to understand my question better

Comment: @Hello With the exception of a leading space, that's true. But your question doesn't say you ran `pkg-config --libs libcurl`. It says you ran `pkg-config --cflags libcurl`. As I've edited my question to show, the output of `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` is quite different from the output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl`.

Comment: I dont deny that. All I am trying to clarify here is what precisely is the point of using pkg-config --cflags when it prints nothing but an extra space

Comment: @Hello That seems very different from what you seem to be asking in your question. You may want to edit your question again for clarification. Even reading these comments, I'm having trouble understanding what information you're asking for at this point.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Fixed title, question. see my answer for what I think he means.